# Question about properties of topological manifold and connected Lie group

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Lie group G is clearly $C^{\infty}$-manifold and I know the conditions that a set is allowed to be (topological) $C^{\infty}$- manifold : Hausdorff space, locally Euclidean, and [second countable basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space).(Of course, [differential structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure) should be given...)  Thus, I have thought that (every) Lie group G has second countable basis... However, I feel confused when reading the following exercise. (Warner's textbook)

> **Prove that connected Lie group is automatically second countable. That is, the assumption of second countability in the definition of connected Lie group is redundant. .....(♣)**

Even though the Lie group is connected or  not, as I mentioned, Lie group has second countable basis because of the definition of (topological) manifold. If (♣) is true, disconnected Lie group would not be second countable?(Apparently, this statement is strange...)
what's wrong in my thought?

Comment: Warner probably uses a different definition of a manifold, one which does not require 2nd countability. The point of the exercise is to see that if $G$ is a connected (Hausdorff) topological group locally homeomorphic to $R^n$ for some $n$, then $G$ is 2nd countable, hence, is a manifold in the traditional sense.

Comment: You should give us the definition of a connected Lie group and of a manifold in Warner's book.

Comment: The second countability assumption for Lie groups/ manifolds is far from universal (I never use it). Indeed for connected Lie groups it is automatic.